# Apply a function to list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices (Note: they vary in dimensions unlike this example):

```
x <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
y <- x+300
mylist <- list(x, y)
```

I want to run a function `networklevel`on each matrix within the list of matrices. The function has various indices that can be calculated; I would like to use the `index= "linkage density"`This function can be found in `install.packages('bipartite')`. I would like the output to be a vector of the values to that function.  I have tried the following code:

```
lapply(mylist, FUN= function(mylist) networklevel(mylist[[i]], index="linkage density"))
```

The answer to this example would be:

```
 output<- c(3.285977, 3.49994)
```

Comment: your attempt is close `lapply(mylist, FUN= function(mylist) networklevel(mylist, index="linkage density"))` should work, although I would do `lapply(mylist, FUN= function(x) networklevel(x, index="linkage density"))` or similar to avoid confusion